# PHP strtotime to return as UTC timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

Its a bit of a sever difference problem. On my local dev. server Im using:

```
<?php print strtotime($date." UCT"); ?>
```

The above code gives me the correct timestamp for my timezone. HOWEVER, the same code returns false on the live server.

The live server has a lower version of php installed and I imagine that to be the problem.

What I'm looking for is an alternative to the above line of code.

I could use the normal strototime without the ." UCT" part and add in 2hours but would rather have PHP handle timezones.

$date looks like this: 2011-05-25 05:48:00

Comment: what is the php version on live server

Comment: What does `$date` look like? And did you mean UTC instead of UCT?

Comment: Does `<?php print strtotime($date." UTC"); ?>` work?

Comment: @Roshan 5.2.6
@Yes, typo corrected. $date = 2011-05-25 05:48:00

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<?php print strtotime($date." UTC"); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php print strtotime($date." UCT"); ?>
```

Comment: @stefgosselin  UCT is also valid timezone . http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: `Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.`

Answer (score 0):

PHP warning on PHP documentation page, no support for UCT there :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

> Warning
>
> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.

And here is latest PECL timezon database :

http://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb

Comment: Blatantly not pointing out that the @Good-bye likely made a typo is rude.

Comment: @capikaw Or may be because it was not a typo, UCT is a supported name for "Universal Coordinated Time" , but is not supported in PHP , and that is what I had mentioned in my answer. See linux for example : ` ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/U*
/usr/share/zoneinfo/UCT  /usr/share/zoneinfo/Universal  /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC`

A misinformed downvote is also rude IMHO.